# Show straight line in react native with different colors

Tags: react-native

How to create UI as shown in image.I need to create straight line showing different colors indicators to show session. Any help will be appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etzLS.png)

Comment: you want colour indicators in any place in straight line or specific place you want to highlight? which means the given image shows highlight based on time. thats why.

Comment: Try using `https://github.com/hectahertz/react-native-color` or custom view

Comment: @Elango based on time I want to highlite colours on line

Comment: @Nooruddin Lakhani Its a slider ..I don't want a slider..its just a simple straight view or line showing different time indicators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@smitha, I don't know you're requirement , just print this. I think, it will return the same, what you're expecting. If you forward anything, let me know.

```
   <View style={{height: 5,flex:0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', backgroundColor: '#ececec'}}>
                            <View style={{height: 5, backgroundColor: '#0472fe', width: 20,borderRadius: 5}}></View>
                            <View style={{height: 5, backgroundColor: '#ff0000', width: 20,borderRadius: 5}}></View>
                            <View style={{height: 5, backgroundColor: '#0472fe', width: 20,borderRadius: 5}}></View>
                            <View style={{height: 5, backgroundColor: '#0472fe', width: 20,borderRadius: 5}}></View>
                        </View>
```

Comment: @Elago can I use a flatlist instead of view to show different session time? It is possible with FlatList?

Comment: I don't know wether it's possible with FL, let me check.